# Apache virtualhost configuration

Tags: apache-2.2, redmine

I am following [this](http://grandslam90.wordpress.com/2012/05/22/howto-redmine-2-0-0-passenger-subversion-repositories-in-ubuntu-12-04/#comment-45) guide to intall redmine.

It has a section on apache2 virtual host configuration.

```
sudo nano /etc/apache2/sites-available/mysite
<VirtualHost *:80>
 ServerName my_domain.com
 DocumentRoot /var/www/redmine
 ServerAdmin user@example.com
 LogLevel warn
 ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/redmine_error
 CustomLog /var/log/apache2/redmine_access combined
 <Directory /var/www/redmine>
 Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
 AllowOverride None
 Order allow,deny
 allow from all
 RailsBaseURI /redmine
 PassengerResolveSymlinksInDocumentRoot on
 </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

In my case, I have a Ubuntu server with static ip

> 192.168.1.100

I need to access the redmine application preferably in a non standard port (instead of ServerName configuration as above and access through `http://my_website`).

So, I need to access the application from another PC (need access only in local subnet) through url

> 192.168.1.100/8888

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just change this line

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
```

to this in order to listen on port 8888

```
<VirtualHost *:8888>
```

And of course restart the server after making this change.